# Model missing when unit testing MVC 5 async controller methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asynchronous, model, controller

Here is my controller method:

```
private IAutoManagerUnitOfWork _work;

public VehiclesController(IAutoManagerUnitOfWork work)
{
    _work = work;
}

public async Task<ViewResult> Index()
{
    return View("Index", await _work.VehicleRepository.GetAll().ToListAsync());
}
```

Here is my NUnit test method:

```
[Test]
public async Task Index_Get_ReturnsViewResult()
{
    MockUnitOfWork uow = new MockUnitOfWork();
    uow.VehicleRepository.Add(new Vehicle { Year = 2011, Make = "Ford", Model = "Mustang", Trim = "GT" });

    var controller = new VehiclesController(uow);

    ViewResult viewResult = await controller.Index();

    var model = (List<Vehicle>)(viewResult.Model);
    Assert.IsTrue(model.Count > 0); // Causes exception because model isn't defined.
}
```

When I step through the test, viewResult.Model is empty (has a Count = 0). I've tried making my test method non-async and doing a task.Wait() after the call to Index(), but the only way I can get it to work is by changing my controller method to a non-async method. I found a couple of examples here on Stack Overflow, but even following those I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `MockUnitOfWork`? Do you mean `Mock<IAutoManagerUnitOfWork>`? If so, you should be using `Setup` instead of modifying instances returned by property getters.

Comment: I'm not currently using Moq. MockUnitOfWork is simply a test version of my unit of work class, which basically encapsulates my repositories.

Comment: In that case, I suspect `MockUnitOfWork` is just returning a new collection from its `VehicleRepository` getter.

Comment: Yes. In my test method, I instantiate the unit of work class and add a record to the collection. Then I pass the class into the Index method of the controller. I have verified that data is being returned from the Index method. It's just not getting back to my test method in the Model property.

Comment: Please post the relevant code for `MockUnitOfWork`.

Comment: did you get your unit test to work?